# $Av_1=Av_2 \neq 0$ implies $v_1=v_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a seemingly simple question, but had me thinking quite a bit...maybe someone has an elegant proof.

For an arbitrary field $\mathscr{F}$ let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathscr{F}$ and $v_1, v_2$ vectors in $\mathscr{F}^n$ such that $Av_1=Av_2 \neq 0$ and suppose $v_2 \neq v_1 +n$ where $n$ is some vector in the null space of $A$ and $n\neq 0$. Note that by the given conditions $A$ is not the zero matrix, and $v_1,v_2$ are not zero vectors. Prove or disprove $v_1=v_2$.

Comment: $A(v_2-v_1)=0$ so that $v_2-v_1$ is in the null space of A, no?

Comment: correct, but you have to show $v_2-v_1=0$, if the result is true

Comment: By assumption, $v_2-v_1\neq n$, so it cannot be in the nullspace of $A$, contradiction.

Comment: The conditions essentially say that $v_2 = v_1$ and you want to show that $v_2 = v_1$. Which is true.

Comment: can you make that clear in a proof?

Comment: You need to change the line "$v_2\neq v_1+n$ for some $n\in\ker(A)$" to "for some $n\neq 0$", because $A(v_2-v_1)=0$, and $0$ is always in the nullspace of $A$. Then the correct condition gives $v_2=v_1+0$, which you want.

Comment: Your restriction that $v_2-v_1$ is not in the null space of $A$, combined with the restriction that $Av_1=Av_2$, which says it is in the null space of A.

Comment: @Paul The restriction that $v_2-v_1$ is not in the nullspace of $A$ is impossible, because $A(v_2-v_1)=0$.

Comment: I agree, but the condition is there in the question.

Comment: What quantification is on $n$? If it says $\forall n\neq 0$, then implication is true. If it says $\exists n$, then implication is not true, since $v_2-v_1\in\ker A$, and the condition then translates to "there is more than one element in $\ker A$".

Comment: YES I needed to specify $n$ is not zero - sorry for that...I corrected the question...I see, the proof is really easy then. Thanks for those who were patient with me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Av_1=Av_2\Rightarrow A(v_1-v_2)=0\Rightarrow v_1-v_2\in N(A)\Rightarrow v_1=v_2.$

Comment: Thanks Rafael, yes it's actually really simple...can't believe I missed that...thanks for your patience

Comment: just to be explicit: $v_1-v_2=n$ so that $v_2=v_1-n$, and since $-n$ cannot be nonzero, the result follows.